# Define property in the Object prototype and get the object's type

Tags: javascript

I have created a property on the `Object`'s prototype that is an object with some functions:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "json", 
{
    value: function()
    {
        return {
            _value: this,
            parse: function()
            {
            }
        };
    },
    enumerable: false
});
```

I want to be able to call this on any object, like:

```
"simple string".json().parse()
// or
var a = {b:1};
a.json().parse()
```

Inside `parse()` function I have `this._value` as the object itself. In the case of a string, the value will be:

```
String {0: "s", 1: "i", 2: "m", 3: "p", 4: "l", 5: "e", 6: " ", 7: "s", 8: "t", 9: "r", 10: "i", 11: "n", 12: "g", length: 13}
```

If I use `typeof(this._value)` will return `"object"`. In the case of an object:

```
Object {b: 1}
```

My question is how can I identify if the object was originally a string since its an object and the `typeof`(correctly) returns me `"object"`?

[Demo of above codes](http://jsfiddle.net/pbCM8/).

<sub>PS: Sorry by the awful title. If somebody has any idea how to make it better self-explained would be nice.</sub>

Comment: Are you looking for [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof)?

Comment: @VisioN yes. It worked! Do you want to answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator:

```
("simple string".json()._value) instanceof String  ===  true
```

Answer (score 1):

For not getting the `this` value casted to an object, you can use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode):

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "json", {
    value: function() {
        "use strict";
        return {
            _value: this,
            parse: function() {
            }
        };
    }
});
typeof "simple string".json()._value // "string"
typeof new String("simple string").json()._value // "object"
```