# Why does returning this result in an object?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain this behaviour to me?

```
Object.prototype.getThis = function () {
  return this;
};

var s = "some text";

console.log(s.getThis()); // [String 'some text']
console.log(typeof s.getThis()) // object
```

Why does `getThis` return an `object`?

Comment: Maybe, Because String is object

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed a String instance is an object, but a string primitive is **not** an object.

Comment: Because sloppy mode.

Comment: @Bergi wouldn't the same things happen in strict mode?

Comment: @Pointy: [Try it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24534295/1048572) :-) A strict method will have a primitive this value

Comment: Sure I tried it, "string" and new String(), I found the "string" has Object prototype functions and also int `var i =3` then can return object number using `typeof i.getThis() === "object"'

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed read my answer.

Comment: Not sure whether [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26073742/1048572) would be an appropriate duplicate

Comment: @Bergi I wouldn't think dup'ing to that would be wrong; it's pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a string primitive value as if it were an object, JavaScript implicitly creates a String instance from it. It's as if you wrote

```
console.log(new String(s).getThis().toString());
```

Primitive values are not objects. However, all the primitive types have built-in Object wrapper types, and those wrapper types are where the various  methods (like `.charAt()`, `.trim()`, `.slice()`, etc) are located.

*edit* — @Bergi points out in a comment that in "strict" mode, the runtime still locates methods from the String and Object prototypes *as if* a String instance were being created, but the methods are invoked such that `this` is a reference to the original primitive value.

Comment: That's not 100% accurate. The method (from the object) still gets called on a primitive, with `thisArg` being the primitive value

Comment: @Bergi thats ES2015 stuff right? So, instead of faking the synthesis of a String instance and letting it go at that, it makes some sort of weird thing and invokes the String or Object prototype methods with `this` bound to the original primitive?

Comment: Nah, it's always been like that. I mean, since strict mode was introduced.

Comment: @Bergi right by "ES2015" I basically meant "new-fangled".  Makes sense and is less weird than the "boxing" objects.